# How to make group of tables repeat according to the number of entries in table in rdl using fyiReporting designer

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I am creating a new report and for this report I need to repeat group of tables per a record.

For example

The top few lines in the image are table records.

thank you for your help in advance.

Example input
[image]

More detail out put
[image]

Comment: I suggest you use a top group

Comment: Sorry to ask, What is a top group? I have never used this and would you be able to provide a simple example of it or link to the top group example? Cheers.

Comment: It is a group you would normally aggregate summary data under, yet I can not determine the ways you want to group your report.

Comment: I am grouping them by person. Actually resolved this by providing extra column to indicate which table each entry should go into(e.g. Type column which indicate which table it need to go to) and group them by the person. Now just reformatting other output files(html, excel, rtf, csv). Thank you for your input. Cheers.